# Testing Functions for Program

Tags: python, function, dictionary, testing, assert

I have a task where I need to create a series of functions that will test a program given to us. The only tests I need to provide are ones that will come out to True

I followed an example and tried to apply it to the specifications that were given but I'm not sure how to tackle the other ones.  This is a very new topic for us in Python and I'd like some help because this will help me learn it a lot faster. Any help is really appreciated. Please show the change in code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of writing a test is generally to pass a complete set of inputs to the function you're testing and verify that they produce the expected output.  For your function this might look something like:

```
def test_pumpernickel():
    # Test some invalid argument types.
    assert pumpernickel(1, 2, 3) is None
    assert pumpernickel([1, 1.5], [2, 2.5], 3) is None
    assert pumpernickel("foo", "bar", "baz") is None

    # Test some True results.
    assert pumpernickel([1], [2, 3], 4)           # 1+3=4
    assert pumpernickel([2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 8)     # 3+5=8
    assert pumpernickel([0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], 1)  # 0+1=1

    # Test some False results.
    assert pumpernickel([1], [2, 3], 5) is False
    assert pumpernickel([], [3], 3) is False
    assert pumpernickel([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], 0) is False
```

If any of the tests fail, it tells you that there's a bug in the function (or maybe that there's a bug in the test -- you need to double-check your understanding of what the function is supposed to do, and how the test is working, to know which it is)!

Comment: Thanks for your input, are there any other tests that I could do instead of those? If you could show some other tests instead of the one that you gave?

Comment: I gave you 9 different tests.  What was wrong with them?

Comment: Nothing is the wrong nevermind, could you remove the false and invalid argument types and just have the True results there? That's all I need for this assignment and I want the reply to have the True tests so someone can refer to them later. I'm going to modify my question now, so please do that so the question makes sense. Thanks for understanding.